# How to install Microsoft Edge browser on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I recently got a new machine at work and decided to install Windows 10 Enterprise 'LTSB'.  Mostly I like its similarity to Windows 7 and its stability.  However, very few organizations even know that LTSB exists.  One of the consequences of that is that many web sites are threatening to drop support for Internet Explorer.  Some of them even think that because I'm on Windows 10, I must have Edge already installed (see https://github.com).  Not true with LTSB.  Not only that, I *cannot* install it through normal means.  I use Edge at home, and while it has its flaws, it's the default browser for many, many of our customers, so I'd like to be able to run it, if only just for testing purposes.  When I go to the [Microsoft Edge homepage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge?tduid=(9a23119f56a83e7b34007d36c20f4111)(259740)(2889926)(DLButton)(Edge)#FAlDyVTG7U6IZfVF.97) and click `Try Now`, after giving permission to open an app, I get the following error:

```
You'll need a new app to open this microsoft-edge  OK
```

The pop-up window has an OK button, which is greyed out and doesn't respond.  I see no way to get past this and actually install Edge.

Is there any way to install Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB?

Comment: Not an answer, but LTSB really isn't intended to be used as a desktop machine.  It is for kiosks and things like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a [ZDNet article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/some-windows-10-enterprise-users-wont-get-microsofts-edge-browser/):

> ...the reason Microsoft won't provide Edge to Enterprise users on LTSB is because the company expects to roll out new features and feature updates to Edge on a regular basis...
>   That means it would be kind of pointless to include the evolving Edge browser if it's not going to be updated.

This is further confirmed by recent Google Searches, where [responses from MS staff](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f801501d-fc18-4425-9a0d-e6fb603a0bc8/windows-10-ltsb-is-it-possible-to-add-edge-browser?forum=win10itprogeneral) are that the following will not be included in LTSB:

> Microsoft Edge, Windows Store client, Cortana (limited search capabilities remain available), Microsoft Mail, Calendar, OneNote, Weather, News, Sports, Money, Photos, Camera, Music, and Clock. Therefore, it’s important to remember that Microsoft has positioned the LTSB model primarily for specialized devices.

LTSB is intended for special scenarios and not for the average desktop, even in a tightly-controlled corporate environment. LTSB is designed for use in Kiosks and other very-special-use systems. The "Long Term" in it's name made lots of big-organization IT groups happy as they thought they'd get some long-term consistency from an OS they could run on their user's computers, but that's not what MS intended this system for.

Comment: Ironically, I *like* that all those things are missing.  I have no need for them.  I really don't even care if it's IE or Edge either, but I do need *something* that's generally supported by the internet.

Comment: What is the target purpose of this computer and the browser need?

Comment: It's my development (web services software) and operations desktop.

Comment: I mainly use the browser for access to development tools (Git, JIRA, Jenkins, StackOverflow, etc.), research and general web browsing.  When I occasionally use the company web app (developed by our client team), I like to use the default browser because none of client team developers do, even though a significant portion of our users do.

Comment: So your organization has deployed LTSB as the standard version for your primary user OS?

Comment: If that is the case then your organization has made the wrong choice. I don't know what pull you have in the org, but you should at least get the LTSB purpose documentation from Microsoft in front of those who do make those decisions so they can make the right choices and get y'all off of LTSB and onto the CBB, which is what they're supposed to be using.

Comment: It's a very small organization, so it was actually *me* that made the choice (but just for me).  I looked at the features sets and descriptions on Microsoft's web sites and it seemed like the sensible choice (the description I read didn't mention that Edge would never be offered).  Even without Edge, it still seems like a good trade-off.  Edge isn't that great, and Cortana and the Store are that annoying.  I guess I'll just switch to Chrome/Firefox when everyone drops support for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft dropped the standard Edge for Edge for Chromium. It's still in insiders testing, but it's available on LTSB, it would be available for older OS but later.

**Go get it there**: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/

A proof, on my personnal laptop (LTSB 2016), now with Edge

[image]

> Microsoft Edge will now be delivered and updated for all supported
>   versions of Windows and on a more frequent cadence. We also expect
>   this work to enable us to bring Microsoft Edge to other platforms like
>   macOS

From this blog: [Microsoft Edge: Making the web better through more open source collaboration](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/06/microsoft-edge-making-the-web-better-through-more-open-source-collaboration/#qhgbmWITZwgrdjv7.97) or see that [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/04/08/microsoft-edge-preview-builds-the-next-step-in-our-oss-journey/#CjjCqlwy8RkR9SbG.97) post too